# ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 2 elements, new values have 3 elements

Tags: python, pandas, syntax-error, data-visualization, pie-chart

This is my code that I plan to use for creating a pie chart.

```
import csv
with open('C:\\Users\Bhuwan Bhatt\Desktop\IP PROJECT\Book1.csv', 'r') as file :
    reader = csv.reader(file)
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def piechart1():
   df=pd.read_csv('data,csv',  sep=' ', index_col=False,skipinitialspace=True\
                 ,error_bad_lines=False,encoding= 'unicode_escape')
   df=df.set_index(['Country'])
   dfl=df.iloc[:,[14]]
   final_df=dfl.sort_values(by='TotalMedal')
   final_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
   final_df.columns=('location','Total cases','Total Deaths')
   final_df=final_df.drop(11,axis='index')
   countries=df['Country']
   tmedals=df['TotalMedal']
   plt.pie(tmedals,labels=countries,explode=(0.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.2),shadow=True,autopct='%0.1f%%')
   plt.title("Olympics data analysis\nTop 10 Countries", color='b',fontsize=12)
   plt.gcf().canva.set_window_title("OLMPICS ANALYSIS")
   plt.show()
```

I get this error for some reason:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'sort_values'
```

This is the CSV file I've been using:

```
Country SummerTimesPart Sumgoldmedal    Sumsilvermedal  Sumbronzemedal  SummerTotal WinterTimesPart Wingoldmedal    Winsilvermedal  Winbronzemedal  WinterTotal TotalTimesPart  Tgoldmedal  Tsilvermedal    Tbronzemedal    TotalMedal
     Afghanistan    14  0   0   2   2   0   0   0   0   0   14  0   0   2   2
     Algeria    13  5   4   8   17  3   0   0   0   0   16  5   4   8   17
     Argentina  24  21  25  28  74  19  0   0   0   0   43  21  25  28  74
     Armenia    6   2   6   6   14  7   0   0   0   0   13  2   6   6   14
```

```
INFO-----> SummerTimesPart  :  No. of times participated in summer by each country
           WinterTimesPart  :  No. of times participated in winter by each country
```

Comment: Why do you need to perform `groupby` here? Do you have possible duplicates in your code? Try to perform `sort_values` on your dataframe, not on a `groupby` outcome.

Comment: The `dfl.groupby('Country')` does not return a dataframe, so `w` is not a dataframe but a "DataFrameGroupBy" object. Hence it has no `sort_values` method.

Comment: @zot8 yes u are right. But this is what i am getting after removing groupby line                                     
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 2 elements, new values have 3 elements

Comment: @DeepakBhatt Please update your question with new error that you are facing. Also put whole error stacktrace and not just the error line.

Comment: @AbhilashAwasthi Could you please check this new error.

Comment: @DeepakBhatt If you face new error, then you should post new question even if on same data/problem. Now as you have updated the question, my below answer doesn't solve that..it would be difficult to understand for the people who searches for solutions on stackoverflow.

Comment: @AbhilashAwasthi   So sorry man wait i am gonna change it like it was before

Comment: @AbhilashAwasthi  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63659746/valueerror-shape-mismatch-objects-cannot-be-broadcast-to-a-single-shape                         COULD YOU PLEASE CHECK IT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you set `Country` as Index and in this line

```
dfl=df.iloc[:,[14]]
```

you just pick one column which is `TotalMedal`.
After sorting and resetting index, you try to change column names by line

```
final_df.columns=('location','Total cases','Total Deaths')
```

Here is the error..you have filtered your dataframe for just one column and after resetting gets `Country` also in column. So you just have two columns in your dataframe and trying to change names of columns by providing three values.

Correct line could be -

```
final_df.columns=('location','TotalMedal')
```